# Iterate array of object and prevent default anchor href link using only javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var people = [
  { firstname:"Micro",  lastname:"Soft", site:"http://microsoft.com" },
  { firstname:"Face",   lastname:"Book", site:"http://facebook.com" },
  { firstname:"App",    lastname:"Le",   site:"http://apple.com" },
  { firstname:"Master", lastname:"Card", site:"http://mastercard.com" }
];
```

and the following list in the DOM:

```
<ul id="people">
  <li><a href="http://microsoft.com">microsoft.com</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://facebook.com">facebook.com</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://apple.com">apple.com</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://mastercard.com">mastercard.com</a></li>
</ul>
```

Assuming that the order of items in the array matches the order of list items in the list (as it does above), attach the necessary event handlers to the DOM so that clicking on any of these links will not take you to the website that is linked in the href, but will instead alert the first name and last name of the person who created the website (as is contained in the array data).

I have managed to prevent the default behavior of anchor tag but not able to get the firsname and last name in the click function.

```js
var listElements = document.getElementById("people").getElementsByTagName("A");
var people = [
  { firstname:"Micro",  lastname:"Soft", site:"http://microsoft.com" },
  { firstname:"Face",   lastname:"Book", site:"http://facebook.com" },
  { firstname:"App",    lastname:"Le",   site:"http://apple.com" },
  { firstname:"Master", lastname:"Card", site:"http://mastercard.com" }
];
for (var i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
            listElements[i].addEventListener('click', function (event, i) {
              event.preventDefault();
            });
        }
```

```html
<ul id="people">
  <li><a href="http://microsoft.com">microsoft.com</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://facebook.com">facebook.com</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://apple.com">apple.com</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://mastercard.com">mastercard.com</a></li>
</ul>
```

Can anybody help me out to get `firstname` and `lastname` within click function ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) and rewrite your code like below to achieve that,

```
for (let i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
  listElements[i].addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(people[i].firstname,people[i].lastname);
  });
}
```

Basically `let` will help us to create a variable scoped to a block, hence the problem caused by the closure will not harm us if we use `let` at this context.

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/hgt6psgw/)

And if your environment doesn't supports ES6, then try to create a scope per iteration like below,

```
for (var i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
  (function(i){
    listElements[i].addEventListener('click', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      console.log(people[i].firstname,people[i].lastname);
    });
  })(i);
}
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/hgt6psgw/1/)

Comment: Or use `.forEach` instead of `for` + IIFE.

Comment: You should explain why *let* is useful, and that it is currently only supported by a subset of browsers in use.

Comment: @FelixKling -> I intended to achieve this through for loop only.

Comment: @AmiteshChauhan That is a modern way of iterating the array. Under the hood while loop will be used for iteration.